# c modulus operator

Tags: c

what happens when you use negative operators with %.
example -3%2 or 3%-2

Comment: @Andrey: Trying doesn't tell you the difference between an absolute language truth and if what you are seeing is implementation dependent.

Comment: The correct name is 'modulo' or 'remainder'.

Comment: @Andrey: "Just trying" is what often leads to *incorrect* conclusions along the lines of "it works on my machine + compiler, so it must be the same everywhere".

Answer (score 3):

In C89, C90, and C++03 the standards requires only that  `(a/b)*b+a%b == a` for the `/` and `%` operators.

If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative;
if not, the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined

Edit: In C99  a negative number will be returned if the first argument is negative

Comment: In C99, Result has the same sign as dividend

Answer (score 3):

In `C99`

```
-3%2=-1
 3%-2=1
```

In `C90`  `-3%2 or 3%-2` --> Implementation defined

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator gives the remainder for integer division, so that `(a / b) * b + (a % b)` is always equal to `a` (if `a / b` is representable; in two's complement notation the most negative integer divided by -1 is not representable).

This means that the behaviour of `%` is coupled to that of `/`. Prior to C99 the rounding direction for negative operands was implementation-defined, which meant that the result of `%` for negative operands was also implementation-defined. In C99 the rounding for `/` is towards zero (decimals are simply truncated), which also fixes the behaviour of `%` in C99.

Answer (score 1):

In C99 a % b has the sign of a, pretty much like fmod in math.h. This is often what you want :

```
unsigned mod10(int a)
{
    int b = a % 10;
    return b < 0 ? b + 10 : b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Kernighan & Ritchie, 2nd edition, page 39, 2.5:

> ...the sign of the result for % are
>   machine-dependent for negative
>   operands, as is the action taken on
>   overflow or underflow.

Comment: K&R is an old book and it would be better if you quote the standards rather than quoting K&R.

Comment: @Satish, I agree, it would be better, but as long as I know the standards are commercial, and I don't have a copy of it. The answer provided by Brian R. Bondy is based on the standards, and you completed it with your comment.