# Unwind angle to 360

Tags: c++, angle

How can I unwind an angle to result in an angle in [0, 360)?
I can do this:

```
int unwind(int angle)
{
    while(angle < 0) angle += 360;
    while(angle >= 360) angle -= 360;
}
```

But I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this without loops. I also tried `angle % 360` but that doesn't work for negative angles (`-60 % 360 == -60`).

Comment: Can't you just add 360 to the result of `angle % 360` if it is negative?

Comment: Use the fmod() function.

Comment: Hans: Why would you use a floating point function on integers?

Comment: @Hans: fmod still suffers from the same issue

Comment: Whoa, why is an angle an integer?  Never mind.

Comment: Actually (though not in the OP's code) it would make perfect sense to keep angles as fixed-point values, because the are of bounded scale, so all those bits could be put to much better use than for a small exponent. You'd need some low-level fixed point functions to make use of those, though, I guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
(360 + (angle % 360)) % 360
```

or:

```
(angle >= 0 ? 0 : 360) + angle % 360
```

Comment: nitpick: for -360, the second version evaluates to 360

Comment: Since the result of `%` isn't predictable (at least in C++98), why not just compute it and do one more check? `angle %= 360; while (angle < 0) angle += 360;` -- that'll do at most one extra addition.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: that isn't an expression, therefore cannot be transformed into a macro and used inside another expression, which IMO is a deal breaker, at least for me. However, can you expand your comment about `%` isn't predictable?

Comment: @Lie: I think it's implementation defined how modulo acts if either operand is negative. I also think that the behaviour was prescribed in C99, but I'm not sure. That said, you could make it an expression at the expense of putting the modulo in there twice: `angle % 360 + (angle % 360 < 0 ? 360 : 0)`.

Comment: @Dani: -235445345 gives me 55. Which works as I expected, what were you expecting?

Comment: re: negative operands: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093014/c-modulus-operator (didn't know this!)